# Optimized solution for Balanced Parentheses Problem

Tags: java, optimization, stack

Given a string containing just the characters `'('`, `')'`, `'{'`, `'}'`, `'['` and `']'`, determine if the input string is valid.

An input string is valid if:

1. Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
2. Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.
3. Note that an empty string is also considered valid.

Example 1:

```
Input: "()[]{}"
Output: true
Example 2:
```

Example 2:

```
Input: "{[(])}"
Output: false
```

My solution for the above problem is:

```
static boolean isPair(char left,char right){
        return left=='{' && right=='}' || left=='(' && right==')' || left=='[' && right==']'; 
    }
    public boolean isValid(String s) {
        Stack<Character> stack= new Stack<>();
        for(char ch: s.toCharArray()){
            if(ch=='(' || ch=='{' || ch=='['){
                stack.push(ch);
            }
            else{
                if(!stack.isEmpty() && isPair(stack.peek(),ch))
                    stack.pop();
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

I have found a much smarter solution somewhere but unable to understand it.
Here's the code:

```
public boolean isValid(String s) {
        Stack<Character> stack= new Stack<>();
        for(char ch: s.toCharArray()){
            if(ch=='(')
                stack.push(')');
            else if(ch=='{')
                stack.push('}');
            else if(ch=='[')
                stack.push(']');
            else if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop()!=ch)
                return false;
        }
        return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

Please help me to understand the working of last `else-if` block.

Comment: Your stack contains the unclosed brackets. The stack in the second example contains the *expected* brackets. That last `else if` just tests that the current character is the expected bracket.

Comment: Why do you think this solution is "optimized"? What is it optimized for?

Comment: I called it optimized only because of the memory usage ....The memory usage of my code is 34.4MB while 34.2MB for this solution on the `LeetCode Platform`.

Comment: @jigneshkumar you would likely use a lot less memory if you used a `StringBuilder` (append/delete) instead of a `Stack` (push/pop), because you would avoid using autoboxed values.

Comment: Also: using an indexed for loop and `s.charAt(i)` is better than `toCharArray()`, since the latter copies the string's char array.

Comment: Thanks for the help, `+Andy Turner` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have pushed the `closing bracket` for all the `opening` brackets. So, that when closing brackets come, then it will match the character at the top of stack. If it doesn't match or stack becomes empty. That means **unbalanced**.

```
else if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop()!=ch)
    return false;
```

When you reach here, you have a `bracket` as ch but the stack is empty or the value from the stack doesn't match the incoming character.

So, the parantheses are **not balanced**.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty similar to your own version.

The main difference is that you push the open brackets to the stack and in `isPair` check if the open bracket on top of the stack matches the closing one you're currently evaluating.

That solution skips it by directly pushing the expected closing bracket to the stack, but functionally it's the same.

That last `if else` does the exact same than your `else`:

1. If `stack.isEmpty()` returns false
2. If not empty and not matching the bracket on top of the stack, returns false
3. Otherwise pops the bracket on top

There is a slight difference that for case 2 that solution pops the stack while in yours you don't pop it. But it doesn't change anything as the function returns and that stack will not be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript solution to the problem

```
var isValid = function (s) {
    if (s.length % 2 !== 0) return false
    // Stack to store left symbols
    const leftSymbols = [];
    // Loop for each character of the string
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        // If left symbol is encountered
        if (s[i] === '(' || s[i] === '{' || s[i] === '[') {
            leftSymbols.push(s[i]);
        }
        // If right symbol is encountered
        else if (s[i] === ')' && leftSymbols.length !== 0 && leftSymbols[leftSymbols.length - 1] === '(') {
            leftSymbols.pop();
        } else if (s[i] === '}' && leftSymbols.length !== 0 && leftSymbols[leftSymbols.length - 1] === '{') {
            leftSymbols.pop();
        } else if (s[i] === ']' && leftSymbols.length !== 0 && leftSymbols[leftSymbols.length - 1] === '[') {
            leftSymbols.pop();
        }
        // If none of the valid symbols is encountered
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return leftSymbols.length === 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding my code here using *map in JavaScript*, Please add if you find a way better than it.

```
`   var isValid = function(s) {
let map={
  ")":"(",
  "]":"[",
  "}":"{"      
}

let _stack = [];
for(let i=0;i<s.length;i++)
  {
    if(s[i]==="(" || s[i]==="[" || s[i]==="{")
      {
        _stack.push(s[i]);
      }
    else if(_stack[_stack.length-1]===map[s[i]])
      {
        _stack.pop();
      }
    else
      return false;
  }
   return  _stack.length?false:true;
  };
```

`