# Solving Problem: Valid Bracket String in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the following program from LeetCode.

Given a string s containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.
An input string is valid if:

1. Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
2. Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.

[This is the problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/)

I have written the following code. It runs for 86/91 test cases. What should I change in the code so that all the test cases run?

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isValid(String s) {
        char a[] = new char[10000];
        int j=0, flag = 0;
        char pop='a';
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i<s.length() ; i++)
        {
            if(s.charAt(0)=='(' || s.charAt(0)=='[' || s.charAt(0)=='{')
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            if(s.length()%2==0)
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            
            if(s.charAt(i)=='(' || s.charAt(i)=='[' || s.charAt(i)=='{')
            {
                if(j<0)
                {
                    j=0;
                }
                a[j]=s.charAt(i);
                j++;
            }
            else if(s.charAt(i)==')' || s.charAt(i)==']' || s.charAt(i)=='}')
            {
                try
                {
                    pop = a[j-1];
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    
                }                
                j=j-2;
                
                if(s.charAt(i)==')')
                {
                    if(pop=='(')
                    {
                        flag=1;
                    }
                }
                else if(s.charAt(i)==']')
                {
                     if(pop=='[')
                    {
                        flag=1;
                    }
                }
                else if(s.charAt(i)=='}')
                {
                    if(pop=='{')
                    {
                        flag=1;
                    }
                }
                
                if(flag == 1)
                {
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(j<0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My program is not working for the following test case:

"({{{{}}}))"

**EDIT:**

LeetCode is showing "({{{{}}}))" as an invalid string. Can anyone tell if this is a valid string or not?

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: your code becomes quite easier to read if you **turn** around your guarding checks. Meaning: instead of having "if X then nothing else return false", do "if !X then return false". You could also put all valid chars into two sets (one for opening, one for closing brackets).

Comment: And the thing to absolutely avoid: having EMPTY catch blocks. There is a good chance your "pop" causes an exception, that is then completely IGNORED. Never ever do that. At least print exceptions, but especially in code that **should not throw** just let them happen, and then fix them!

Comment: So, step one: read [mcve], and improve your question accordingly, for example by you yourself trying to find valid/invalid inputs that give the wrong results!

Comment: `j=j-2` seems very wrong for the "pop" operation.  You **add _one_** to `j` when pushing one character onto stack; why not **subtract _one_** when popping one back off?

Comment: I am under the impression this might be a perfect scenario for a `Stack`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson This is for when an element gets pushed, j is incremented by 1. So, if in the next iteration, if pop operation is to be carried out the control needs to go two steps backwards.

Comment: So, one step forward for every left-bracket pushed on, but **two** steps back for every right-bracket popped off?  That makes no sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimized solution for Balanced Parentheses Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117715/optimized-solution-for-balanced-parentheses-problem)

Comment: @KevinAnderson Using this program more than 90% of the test cases were executed. I did what I did was because the program flow required me to write the program in that manner.

Comment: @Joe I understood the problem. However, I am trying to implement the stack using an array. Can you please help regarding that?

Comment: @Joe Can you tell if "({{{{}}}))" is a valid string or not?. LeetCode is showing "({{{{}}}))" as an invalid string. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @Koenigsberg stated in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868110/solving-problem-valid-bracket-string-in-java#comment118201451_66868110), using a [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html) to implement the solution seems appropriate.

```java
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Solution {
    private static final char CURLY = '{';
    private static final char CURLY_CLOSE = '}';
    private static final char ROUND = '(';
    private static final char ROUND_CLOSE = ')';
    private static final char SQUARE = '[';
    private static final char SQUARE_CLOSE = ']';

    private static boolean isCloser(char opener, char closer) {
        return switch (opener) {
                   case CURLY -> closer == CURLY_CLOSE;
                   case ROUND -> closer == ROUND_CLOSE;
                   case SQUARE -> closer == SQUARE_CLOSE;
                   default -> false;
               };
    }

    private static boolean isOpener(char ch) {
        return ch == CURLY  ||  ch == ROUND  || ch == SQUARE;
    }

    private static boolean isValid(String input) {
        boolean valid = true;
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char symbol = input.charAt(i);
            if (isOpener(symbol)) {
                stack.push(symbol);
            }
            else {
                if (isCloser(stack.peek(), symbol)) {
                    try {
                        stack.pop();
                    }
                    catch (EmptyStackException xEmptyStack) {
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (valid) {
            valid = stack.empty();
        }
        return valid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputs = {"()",
                           "()[]{}",
                           "(]",
                           "([)]",
                           "{[]}",
                           "({{{{}}}))"};
        for (String input : inputs) {
            System.out.printf("%-5b: %s%n", isValid(input), input);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that method `isCloser`, in the above code, uses [switch expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html) which were introduced in JDK 12.

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
true : ()
true : ()[]{}
false: (]
false: ([)]
true : {[]}
false: ({{{{}}}))
```

### EDIT

As requested by OP in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868110/solving-problem-valid-bracket-string-in-java/66869904#comment118211606_66869904), below, here is an implementation of a stack for `char`s. Just replace `Stack` in the above code with `CharStak`.

```java
class CharStak {
    private static final int  SIZE = 100;

    private char[]  charr;
    private int count;

    public CharStak() {
        charr = new char[SIZE];
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return count == 0;
    }

    public char peek() {
        checkEmpty();
        return charr[count - 1];
    }

    public char pop() {
        checkEmpty();
        return charr[--count];
    }

    public void push(char ch) {
        charr[count++] = ch;
    }

    private void checkEmpty() {
        if (empty()) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used an array to implement the stack. Can you look into my solution once again?

Comment: @AnwesaRoy the [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/solution/) on _leetcode_ also uses class `java.util.Stack`. Are you trying to implement your own _stack_ at the expense of finding an efficient solution to the problem?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to implement the stack using an array. The program doesn't face any "Execution Timed Out" error for the test cases for which it got executed which is more than 90% of the test cases. So I guess an array may be used for this problem.

Comment: @AnwesaRoy I'm not going to debug your code, there are debuggers for that. Every programmer needs to learn how to debug code. Your IDE should have a debugger. Learn how to use it.

Comment: Can you tell if "({{{{}}}))" is a valid string or not?. LeetCode is showing "({{{{}}}))" as an invalid string.  Thanks.

Comment: @AnwesaRoy my code, in my answer above, shows that the string `({{{{}}}))` is invalid. Look at the part of my answer that shows the program output and you will see the following: `false: ({{{{}}}))` which means that it is not valid.